# startActivityForResultIntent result=None

Tags: qpython, storage-access-framework

I'm using qpython on Android and am attempting the following:

```
import androidhelper

droid = androidhelper.Android()

action = "android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"
mimetype = "image/*"
categories = ["android.intent.category.OPENABLE"]
intent = droid.makeIntent(action, None, mimetype, None, categories).result

activity = droid.startActivityForResultIntent(intent)
```

After selecting an image in the picker, the result is:

```
Result[id=1, result=None, error=None]
```

Why can't I get a url result from this?

Thanks in advance!